# how do i change timezone using adb

Tags: android, adb

I want to change the timezone using adb shell command.

I went through some posts which allow changing it in linux, but they are not valid for android.

Answer (score 44):

For the list of tzdata values I go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

To set the timezone use `setprop persist.sys.timezone <TZ>` command:

```
setprop persist.sys.timezone "America/Chicago"
```

Comment: Does not appear to work on Nougat on a generic Qualcomm device. `getprop` shows the value, but `setprop` has no effect. I assume one might need root.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742253/unable-to-change-timezone-on-android-device-using-adb-shell-setprop?rq=1

Comment: Requires Root and Reboot to take effect in the Android Settings
$ADB_CMD shell setprop persist.sys.timezone "America/Los_Angeles"

Answer (score 16):

`adb shell service call alarm 3 s16 America/Phoenix`, which will be effective immediately.

`setprop` with `persist.sys.timezone` only works after reboot.

Comment: This one should be the preferred answer =)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer which does not need system root

Comment: The answer could use some explanation about the parameters for the alarm.

Comment: With this command I could set my custom timezone that was my need! ```adb shell service call alarm 3 s16 GMT+3:30```

Answer (score 4):

```
adb shell service call alarm 4 s16 America/Chicago
```

4 - stands for the fourth function in alarm service implementation.

s16 - stands for string argument type.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34625/where-to-find-description-of-all-system-bin-service-calls

Comment: This is the best answer since it takes effect immediately, and broadcasts Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED for anyone listening.  On my Android 11 system it is "alarm 3 s16 America/Chicago",  so please find the correct IAlarmManager.aidl file for your OS version and find the index of setTimeZone()

Answer (score 0):

In my (very) limited experience I have been able to edit the /system/build.prop file. I change the line in there that says persist.sys.timezone=America/Sao_Pao or some such drival to persist.sys.timezone=America/Chicago for my timezone CDT. I also changed the lines persist.sys.language=bt and persist.sys.country=AR to persist.sys.language=en and persist.sys.country=US respectively.

There are a few other things you can tweak in the file that will persist after a system restore. You might want to make sure that the build.prop file in a flash image or directory has the correct lines in it.

The /system/property directory seems to hold several text files with a single value. These seem to show up after using setprop but  the OS doesn't seem to reflect the changes.

Editing these files usually does require root access either with a term program or the ADB.exe shell. (ADB = Android Device Bridge available in the Android SDK) I found ADB.exe  while looking through the firmware downloads at JXD.HK for the S18 MiniPad. In the files.rar dl there is also the SuperUser.apk and a rooted version of busybox and su.

Best of Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this https://gist.github.com/jpkrause/6b7e576894a800d451bf for answer to your question.

So in your case it would be: 
adb shell setprop persist.sys.timezone America/Chicago

Answer (score -2):

This works with ADB

Get current global time zone:

```
adb shell settings get global time_zone
```

Set a time zone:

```
adb shell settings put global time_zone Europe/Madrid
```

Time zones list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: I don't see that set on my Marshmallow device, and there's no entry for it in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html .

Comment: @Alex I've tried to do so , but I dont really see any changes on my device / emulator , the time zone is still the one I had before the change , any idea what went wrong ?

Comment: I concur with @Igal, this is not doing anything

Comment: There's only `AUTO_TIME_ZONE` in `Settings` which does something else. This indeed does nothing.

Answer (score -3):

I changed 2 files to change my timezone.

the one that i don't entire know if it's necessary, but it keeps things in sync:

```
  /etc/timezone
```

the more one you for sure need to change:

```
  /etc/localtime
```

from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-tz-environment-variable/ you can determine the name of the timezone you want with `tzselect`.

I took inspiration from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-and-time-timezone-in-freebsd/
and copied my timezone file from `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` to `/etc/localtime`.

`/etc/timezone` is a text file with the name of the timezone.  so i just updated it to match the value provided by `tzselect`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you missed the part where the original post mentioned "Android". # cd /etc/timezone
cd: can't cd to /etc/timezone
# cd /etc/localtime
cd: can't cd to /etc/localtime

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere, i think you need to re-read my post.  /etc/timezone is a text file, so you can't cd to it.  it's a file that needs to be edited.  /etc/localtime is also a text file that needs to be edited.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere, I will also say that this was definitely on my Android device, which i had rooted. So, whether or not you're able to edit those files might be dependent on whether or not you've rooted your device.

Comment: Is /etc/localtime really a textfile? I thought it's a link to a time zone file in /usr/share/zoneinfo. Instead of editing /etc/localtime, I would try to link it to the correct time zone file.