# Change android time zone on emulator via adb shell

Tags: android, adb

I'm running tests for my app, and I want to validate that it works in various time zones.
I'm trying solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062827/how-do-i-change-timezone-using-adb) running `adb shell setprop persist.sys.timezone "Pacific/Honolulu"`, but the timezone (and time) on emulator is not changing- can this work without restarting the device?

Comment: did you get any luck finding how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean UI tests, I can not change android  `Date & Time` settings on emulator via adb shell.

The only solution I found is to set the timezone during the creation of the emulator with `-timezone` option.

For example, you can create android emulator with a command like `$ emulator @Nexus_5X_API_23 -timezone Europe/Paris`.

See more emulator command line options [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html)