# Unable to set Time zone using adb setprop: failed to set property 'persist.sys.timezone'

Tags: android, adb

Used below command to set time zone from adb:

```
user$ adb shell setprop persist.sys.timezone $"GMT-11.00"
```

Below error comes:

```
setprop: failed to set property 'persist.sys.timezone' to 'GMT-11.00'
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742253/unable-to-change-timezone-on-android-device-using-adb-shell-setprop